# Attach instrument rack to drywall over brick

Tags: drywall, mounting, drywall-anchor

I have a non-functional fireplace. The brick chimney is covered by a sheet of drywall. I have a [recorder stand](https://www.recorderstands.com/store/p103/Horizontal_Stand.html) and I would like to mount it above the mantel. The weight of the stand is 1.25 kg (2.76 lb), and the instruments weigh a total of 1.61 kg (3.55 lb), for a total of 2.86 kg (6.31 lb).

I have some 1″ threaded metal drywall anchors. Assuming that the drywall and whatever is backing it is thick enough (which I suppose I'd find out by drilling a pilot hole), should three of these anchors be sufficient to hold that load?

Comment: 6 pounds isn't alot.  But why wouldn't you use concrete anchors????

Comment: Concrete anchors are usually rate for something silly like 300 pounds. You'll be fine as long as your not drilling into crumbling brick/mortar.

Comment: I wouldn't use concrete anchors primarily because they're more work and require more tools (which I'd have to borrow). But I could use them if the use case warrants them. If drywall anchors alone would not be enough, then that would be a valuable answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible meanings to "The brick chimney is covered by a sheet of drywall.":

- Frame (studs) attached to bricks (or possibly to floor and ceiling) and drywall attached to frame.

In this case, the best thing to do is to find the studs and either use screws through the item you are trying to mount into the studs, or use screws to attach a piece of wood to the studs and then attach the other items to the wood.

- Drywall attached directly to bricks (e.g., glued)

In this case, you should use mounting hardware designed for bricks/mortar, such as [Tapcons](https://www.tapcon.com/). This will require a hammer drill.

Comment: Well, I haven't biopsied the wall yet, but it sounds like there's something solid behind the drywall, not spaced studs, and I infer that it's probably the original brick. If I start drilling and find that that assumption was wrong, then I'll have to re-evaluate. Under that assumption, are you saying that mere drywall anchors would not suffice and that I need to attach directly to the bricks?

Comment: If it is solid then you *can't* use regular drywall anchors, because they are based on the assumption that there is hollow space behind the drywall for the back half of the anchor to grip/expand/etc.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The anchors I have are self-drilling non-expanding anchors. As I understand it, they should function here, as long as they don't run into the brick. The downside is that they can't hold nearly as much weight as expanding anchors, but for this use case I think they should hold enough.

Comment: Normally, I'd agree with this advice, however, it seems a bit overkill for all of 6 lbs including the shelf itself. However... shelves tend to collect clutter and/or be repurposed for other things that may weigh more than 6lbs, so some extra strength in the mounting is a good idea...

Comment: @ThomSmith - "as long as they don't run into the brick" - If there's a 3/4" gap behind the drywall, because it's furred-out, if you take a linesman and clip the tip off, it'll fit. If it's glued to the brick, you're screwed (tapcon time). - Looking at the 'shelf' it's more like peg pull-up bars. Perhaps overkill is warranted.